# Make a counter of correct answers

Tags: python

I made a test with 5 questions. First you ask the person's name, then you answer the questions. At the end, you need to display the number of correct answers and the name of the person. The problem is that when I answer 1 question, the following questions do not appear

```
  a=str(input("Введите ФИО: "))
s = a
print("Срез строки: " , s[4::-2])
print("Применение метода к строке ФИО: " , a.islower())
print("Применение метода к строке среза: " , s.islower())
global balli
balli=0

print('Вопрос 1: Какую функцию нужно использовать для ввода данных?\n1). onput.\n2). input.\n3). inpot.')
x = True
n = input()
if n == '2':
    print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    balli +=1
else:
    print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
x=False
if x==True:
    y = True
    print('Вопрос 2: Что произойдет в данном случае (s1+s2)?\n1). сложение строк.\n2). деление строки на 2 части.\n3). повторение строки.')
n2 = input()
if n2 == '1':
    print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    balli +=1
else:
    print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    y = False
    if y == True:
        z = True
    print('Вопрос 3: Закончите фразу. Абстрактным называется класс, который содержит один и более абстрактных ... '
          '\n1). конструкторов.\n2). методов.\n3). классов.')

    n3 = input()
    if n3 == '2':
        print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
        balli += 1
    else:
        print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
z = True
if z==True:
    q = True
print('Вопрос 4: Как нужно обозначить оператор извлечения среза?\n1). ().\n2). {}.\n3). [].')

n4 = input()
if n4 == '3':
    print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    balli +=1
else:
    print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
q=False
if q==True:
    w = True
print('Вопрос 5: Какой из этих операторов прерывает цикл?\n1). break.\n2). else.\n3). continue.')

n5 = input()
if n5 == '1':
    print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    balli +=1
else:
    print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
w=False
print(a, balli)
```

Comment: `x=False; if x==True: ` will always not be `True`, so it will never enter the second question.

Comment: Is the code you posted the full code or just a part of it? It seems like there must be more of that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have set `x` to `False` right before checking if `x` is `True`. In this case `x` will always be `False`.

A few suggestions:

1. Improve variable names
2. When checking if a variable is `True`, you don't have to use `if x == True:`. You can say `if x:`
3. Global variables are for functions. They don't mean anything when used outside of functions. Note: Global variables are not recommended in functions.
4. It's preference but you can print and take input with just the input function. `input("Give me a number: ")`. But keep in mind it will return a string.

Answer (score 0):

I cant read the print statements, but this part of you loop does not make sense

```
if n2 == '1':
    print('Правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    balli +=1
else:
    print('Не правильно, следующий вопрос...')
    y = False
    if y == True:
        z = True
    print('Вопрос 3: Закончите фразу. Абстрактным называется класс, который содержит один и более абстрактных ... '
          '\n1). конструкторов.\n2). методов.\n3). классов.')
```

you set y to false and then create an if statement checking if its true

Answer (score 0):

I liked the premise of a quiz-program, so I quickly put together one of my own. It's not optimal at all, but it keeps score, and verifies that you're answering with numbers, so that we can more easily verify a correct answer.

Here it is:

```
def asker(question, alternatives, answer):
    print(question)
    for idx, alt in enumerate(alternatives):
        idx +=1
        print(f'{idx}. {alt}')
    while True:
        try:
            ans = input("Answer(q to skip): ")
            ans = int(ans)
            break
        except ValueError:
            if ans.lower() == "q":
                return False
            print("Error, answer has to be a number. Please try again.")
            return asker(question, alternatives, answer)
    if ans == answer:
        return True
    return False

questions = [
    [
        "What is colder, -40C or -40F?", # The question itself
        ["-40C", "-40F", "They are both as cold"], # The alternatives of the question
        3 # Answer, as an integer
    ],
    [
        "Who was the first president of the United States of America?",
        ["George Washington", "Thomas Jefferson", "Abraham Lincoln"],
        1
    ],
    [
        "Are clowns scary?",
        ["Yes!", "No!"],
        1
    ]
]

player = input("Name of the Player: ")

score = []
for q in questions:
    score.append(asker(*q))

print("Results of the Quiz:")
print(f"'{player}' got {sum(score)} out of {len(questions)} correct!")
print("Congratulations!")
```

And here is a demo:

```
Name of the Player: Hampus
What is colder, -40C or -40F?
1. -40C
2. -40F
3. They are both as cold
Answer(q to skip): 3
Who was the first president of the United States of America?
1. George Washington
2. Thomas Jefferson
3. Abraham Lincoln
Answer(q to skip): 2
Are clowns scary?
1. Yes!
2. No!
Answer(q to skip): 1
Results of the Quiz:
'Hampus' got 2 out of 3 correct!
Congratulations!
```